# How am I able to replace duplicates in a dataframe column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

say my column is something like this:

```
trade_signal
buy
buy
buy
buy
sell
sell
sell
sell
buy
buy
buy
sell
sell
buy
sell
buy
```

I would like to drop the duplicate elements in the column and replace them with NAN or 0 so it would end up with something like:

```
trade_signal
buy
nan
nan
nan
sell
nan
nan
nan
buy
nan
nan
sell
nan
buy
sell
buy
```

I am completely unsure of the logic I can use to do this, I think I would forward fill up until the next change in signal with NAN values somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try mask with shift:

```
df['trade_signal'] = df['trade_signal'].mask(df['trade_signal'].eq(
                                            df['trade_signal'].shift())
                                             )
```

---

```
  trade_signal
0           buy
1           NaN
2           NaN
3           NaN
4          sell
5           NaN
6           NaN
7           NaN
8           buy
9           NaN
10          NaN
11         sell
12          NaN
13          buy
14         sell
15          buy
```

Comment: thank you this is great, is it possible to fill nans up until the next buy/sell signal? so if it went buy,nan,nan,buy,nan,sell it would end up like buy,nan,nan,nan,nan,sell

Comment: @Jason_Leto can you give me an example series dict ? (also try the code once since I think this will handle that)

Comment: The code doesnt do that, for example df['Trade_Signal'] = pd.Series(np.array(['buy', 'NaN', 'Buy', 'Nan', 'Sell'])) i would like to be all nans between the first buy and last element(sell)

Comment: Sorry I used that as an example, changed it above. It gives me ['buy'',nan','buy',nan,'sell'] i would like ['buy'',nan''nan,nan,'sell']

Comment: @Jason_Leto just do `df['trade_signal']=df['trade_signal'].ffill()` before trying this code and  let me know